# How to solve the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm pretty sure it's easy but this is the first time I have to solve a differential equation.

Given the following equation to solve:

> $ty' + 2y = \sin(t)$.

I have no idea how to start solving it,

can you please explain me detaily?.. thanks in advance.

Comment: WHat did you try ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici tried to solve as ordinary equation but it didn't seem to work..

Comment: Ordinary differential equation, do you mean ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, equation without function .. for example, x = 2y

Comment: Did you learn about differential equations (they mix functions and their derivatives) ? What you post is not an algebraic equation (you even say it in the title of your post). SO, let us see what you know and we shall continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiplication by $t$, we get $$t^2 y'+2 t y=t \sin{t},$$ $$\frac{d}{dt}(t^2 y)=t\sin{t},$$ or
$$t^2 y=\int t \sin{t} dt, $$
$$t^2 y=-t \cos{t}+\sin{t}+C.$$
Finally, $$y=-\frac{\cos{t}}{t}+\frac{\sin{t}}{t^2}+\frac{C}{t^2}.$$

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

General principle: Usually when you see an expression like $f(t)y'(t)+g(t)y(t)$, a standard idea is to find a function $h$ (called the *integrating factor*) such that $[f(t)h(t)]'=g(t)h(t)$. Then we note that $[f(t)h(t)y(t)]' = h(t)f(t)y'(t) + h(t)g(t)y(t) = h(t)[f(t)y'(t)+g(t)y(t)]$, and we can use this to simplify the original DE.

In this case, we multiply the equation by a function $h(t)$. This gives
$$
h(t) t y'(t) + 2 h(t) y'(t) = h(t) \sin(t)
$$
If the function $h$ was chosen such that $[h(t)t]'=2h(t)$, we get
$$
[h(t)ty(t)]' = h(t) \sin(t),
$$
and we can start solving the problem by integrating, if we know how to integrate the RHS. Remember the constant!

Now the problem is reduced to these parts:

1. What is a function $h(t)$ such that $[h(t)t]' = 2h(t)$?
2. What is an integral $F(t)$ of $h(t)\sin(t)$?
3. Solving $y(t)$ from $h(t) t y(t) = F(t) + C$.

Comment: After reading the comments to the question, I understand this may be too advanced for the OP. Comments are welcome!